# MATLAB: creating circular centered text labels for a circular plot

Tags: matlab, plot, text

this is the first time that I post something on stackoverflow, so please excuse me if the post is not top quality.

I am trying to make a figure in MATLAB with some interconnected nodes arranged in a circle, and I would like to label each of these nodes (for example, 1 2 3, etc.). When I use this sample code with the "Rotation" commented out (last line), I get badly aligned text labels. What can I do to have them equidistantly placed from the node plot without having to rotate the text? Thank you all in advance! (I attach the figure that the code is generating).

```
%# 60-by-60 sparse adjacency matrix
A = bucky();
N = length(A);![enter image description here][1]

%# x/y coordinates of nodes in a circular layout
r =  1;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,N+1)'; theta(end) = [];
xy = r .* [cos(theta) sin(theta)];

%# labels of nodes
txt = cellstr(num2str((1:N)','%02d'));

%# show nodes and edges
figure(123)
line(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'LineStyle','none', ...
'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',15, 'Color','g')
hold on
gplot(A, xy, 'b-')
axis([-1 1 -1 1]); axis equal off
hold off

%# show node labels
h = text(xy(:,1).*1.05, xy(:,2).*1.05, txt, 'FontSize',8);
%set(h, {'Rotation'},num2cell(theta*180/pi))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is your text is aligned left.  You put your text boxes at all the points around the circle plus some radial offset. This causes your text labels to appear off center with the left alignment.  If you change the text alignment to center this will alleviate this issue.

The following is an example edit to your code you can use to achieve what you want.  Note, I also increased the radial offset a little too.

```
 %# show node labels
 h = text(xy(:,1).*1.08, xy(:,2).*1.08, txt, 'FontSize',8);
 set(h, {'HorizontalAlignment'},{'center'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I had tried that too, as you say, it alleviates the issue but does not quite solve it. That becomes evident if I use your lines of code with the radial offset to 1.01. Perhaps there are any other suggestions?

Comment: If you try set(h,{'edgecolor'},{'black'}), you gain some more insight on the text box.  With the radial multiplier to 1.0, it looks fairly centered to me.  I am not quite seeing how it's off.